# Controlling Philips Hue using OpenHAB in Raspberry Pi

Tags: philips-hue, openhab

I want to control the Philips Hue Lux color lamps with OpenHAB. So I wonder what are the steps I should do and if I am missing something.

In `pi@raspberrypi:/opt/openhab/configurations/rules $ sudo vi demo.rules`

```
rule "Select scene"
    when
        Item scene received command
    then
        switch(receivedCommand) {
            /*alles uit */
            case 0 : {
            sendCommand(Toggle_7, OFF); 
            sendCommand(Toggle_3, OFF);
            sendCommand(Toggle_1, OFF);
            sendCommand(Toggle_10, OFF);
            sendCommand(Toggle_11, OFF);
            sendCommand(Toggle_5, OFF);
            sendCommand(Toggle_9, OFF);
            }
            /*sfeer */
            case 1 : { 
            sendCommand(LWD_3, 90);
            sendCommand(Color_7, "45.584415,86.033516,70.19608");
            sendCommand(Color_1, "45.584415,86.033516,70.19608");
            sendCommand(Color_10, "45.584415,86.033516,70.19608");
            sendCommand(Color_11, "45.584415,86.033516,70.19608");
            sendCommand(Color_5, "45.584415,86.033516,70.19608");
            sendCommand(LWD_9,10);
            }
            /*Alles aan */
            case 2 : {
            sendCommand(Toggle_7, ON); 
            sendCommand(Toggle_3, ON);
            sendCommand(Toggle_1, ON);
            sendCommand(Toggle_10, ON);
            sendCommand(Toggle_11, ON);
            sendCommand(Toggle_5, ON);
            sendCommand(LWD_9,100);
            }
            /*eten */
            case 3 : {
            sendCommand(Toggle_3, OFF);
            sendCommand(Color_7, "42.391304,73.6,100.0");
            sendCommand(Color_1, "42.391304,73.6,100.0");
            sendCommand(Color_10, "42.391304,73.6,100.0");
            sendCommand(Color_11, "60,42,100");
            sendCommand(Color_5, "60,42,100");
            sendCommand(LWD_9,10);        
            }
            case 4 : {
            /*nacht */
            sendCommand(LWD_9, 50);
            sendCommand(Color_7, "46.25,37.64706,100.0");
            sendCommand(Color_10, "46.25,37.64706,100.0");
            sendCommand(Toggle_1, OFF);
            sendCommand(Toggle_3, OFF);
            sendCommand(Toggle_11, OFF);
            sendCommand(Toggle_5, OFF);
            }
            case 5 : {
                /* Sunset */
            sendCommand(Color_7, "42.391304,73.6,100.0");
            sendCommand(Color_1, "42.391304,73.6,100.0");
            sendCommand(Color_10, "42.391304,73.6,100.0");
            sendCommand(Color_11, "42.391304,73.6,100.0");
            sendCommand(Color_5, "42.391304,73.6,100.0");
            sendCommand(Toggle_3, OFF);
            sendCommand(LWD_9,10);        
            }
            case 6 : {
                /* Aqua */
            sendCommand(Color_7, "230.82353,100.0,100.0");
            sendCommand(Color_1, "230.82353,100.0,100.0");
            sendCommand(Color_10, "230.82353,100.0,100.0");
            sendCommand(Color_11, "230.82353,100.0,100.0");
            sendCommand(Color_5, "230.82353,100.0,100.0");
            sendCommand(Toggle_3, OFF);
            sendCommand(LWD_9,10);        
            }
            case 7 : {
            /* Duo */
            sendCommand(Color_7, "272,100.0,100.0");
            sendCommand(Color_5, "272,100.0,100.0");
            sendCommand(Color_1, "330,100.0,100.0");
            sendCommand(Color_10, "330,100.0,100.0");
            sendCommand(Color_11, "330,100.0,100.0");
            sendCommand(Toggle_3, OFF);
            sendCommand(LWD_9,10);        
            }

            case 8 : {
            /* Duo ambilight play */
            sendCommand(Color_7, "272,100.0,30.0");
            sendCommand(Color_5, "272,100.0,30.0");
            sendCommand(Color_1, "330,100.0,30.0");
            sendCommand(Color_10, "330,100.0,30.0");
            sendCommand(Color_11, "330,100.0,30.0");        
            }
            case 9 : {
            /* Duo ambilight pauze*/
            sendCommand(Color_7, "272,100.0,100.0");
            sendCommand(Color_5, "272,100.0,100.0");
            sendCommand(Color_1, "330,100.0,100.0");
            sendCommand(Color_10, "330,100.0,100.0");
            sendCommand(Color_11, "330,100.0,100.0");
            }
        }
end
```

in `pi@raspberrypi:/opt/openhab/configurations/items $ vi demo.items`

I have
:

```
/* Hue */
Switch Toggle_1   "left bulb"   (Switching) {hue="1"}
Switch Toggle_2   "center bulb" (Switching) {hue="2"}
Switch Toggle_3       "right bulb"  (Switching) {hue="3"}

Color Color_1     "left bulb"   (Colorize)  {hue="1"}
Color Color_2         "center bulb" (Colorize)  {hue="2"}
Color Color_3     "right bulb"  (Colorize)  {hue="3"}

Dimmer Dimm_1     "left bulb"   (WhiteDimmer)   {hue="1;brightness;30"}
Dimmer Dimm_2     "center bulb" (WhiteDimmer)   {hue="2;brightness;30"}
Dimmer Dimm_3     "right bulb"  (WhiteDimmer)   {hue="3;brightness;30"}

Dimmer CT_Dimm_1      "left bulb"   (CTDimmer)  {hue="1;colorTemperature;30"}
Dimmer CT_Dimm_2      "center bulb" (CTDimmer)  {hue="2;colorTemperature;30"}
Dimmer CT_Dimm_3      "right bulb"  (CTDimmer)  {hue="3;colorTemperature;30"}
```

in `pi@raspberrypi:/opt/openhab/configurations $ vi openhab.cfg`:

I have:

```
############################### Philips Hue Binding ###################################
#
# IP address of Hue Bridge (optional, default is auto-discovery)
hue:ip=192.168.1.117
hue:secret=openHABRuntime
hue:refresh=10000
```

I ran it using `sudo ./start.sh` and then paired the Hue hub with OpenHAB. I am not what is missing because still I can't control the Hue with OpenHAB.

[image]

[image]

[image]

My main struggle is connecting the web UI to the code in openHAB. Any pointer is really appreciated! Also I have stitched the code above from various tutorials so it possibly would make no sense at all!

Comment: What do you use to communicate with devices? *(RaspBee, Elelabs ZigBee, CC2531, ConBee 2)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing how the UI's look is done with the *.sitemap files.
This files define how and which items are shown in the UI:
https://github.com/openhab/openhab/wiki/Explanation-of-Sitemaps

As for the rest of the example:
- Are you sure about the ip and secret of the Hue bridge?
- How many light bulbs are connected to the bridge? Because in the *.items file hue=1 means the first bulb connected to your bridge.

Comment: Yeah  I am sure about IP of the hue, I thought the hue secret is a random string, isn't it like so?

Answer (score 0):

It is random yes but you also have to pair the bridge. Have you got it do at least one bulb can turn on and off?

Just checking but your `switch` and `scene` items are not called switch and scene are they?

The binding is picky and you might have to declare the variable type for each:

```
var DecimalType hue = new DecimalType(240) // 0-360; 0=red, 120=green, 240=blue, 360=red(again)
var PercentType sat = new PercentType(100) // 0-100
var PercentType bright = new PercentType(100) // 0-100
var HSBType light = new HSBType(hue,sat,bright)
sendCommand(Light_GF_Lounge_C, light)
```

Though to be frank, the binding is a bit of a pain and you would be better off using the API directly and then setting scenes you have set in an app or something.

Or directly

```
rule "Set lights"
when
    Item Switch_Lounge received update ON
then
    var String hueApiCall = "curl@@-X@@PUT@@-d@@{\"on\": %s, \"hue\":%d , \"sat\": %d, \"bri\": %d, \"transitiontime\": %d}@@http://192.168.1.147/api/YOURPAIREDHUEUSERID/groups/%d/action"
    executeCommandLine(String::format(hueApiCall, true, 13088, 212, 100, 10, 2 ))
end
```

Each of the values in the `executeCommandLine` match the % placeholders in order, in this example on: true, hue: 13088, sat: 212, bri, 100, transition time: 10, group 2

Using that syntax you can set scenes, alerts, all sorts.